# Align text with Java Graphics 2d

Tags: java, java-2d

Can anyone tell me how to alight text right in Java 2d?

Here's the code, it draws a column of text that is naturally aligned left.

```
Font yFont = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 13);

interval = 0;

g2d.setFont(yFont);
for (String l : binLabels) {
     g2d.drawString(l, 0, (135 + interval));
     interval = interval + 15;
}
```

Driving me crazy.
Thanks y'all

slothishtype

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your paintComponent() method you can use the FontMetrics to get the width of the string you want to paint:

```
FontMetrics fm = getFontMetrics( getFont() );
int width = fm.stringWidth("your string here");
```

Then you calculate the offset where to start painting based on the width of the component.

The question is why are you trying to do this. You can just use a JLabel and set its alignment to the right.

Comment: Do I have to use a layout manager to position the JLabel then?

Comment: Yes, you should always be using a layout manager to create a GUI.

Comment: there lies the problem, I am not developing a gui - in the traditional sense - so I was positioning text differently.  Either way, thanks for your help....